# Advanced Custom Fields code displayed as plaintext when written in Code Snippets plugin. How to fix?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, code-snippets

On Wordpress, I’m trying to add a link to single product page using Code Snippets with Advanced Custom Fields. Instead of a link, my code displays as plaintext.

I have tried this code:

```
function product_datasheet_below_summary() { ?>
    $link = get_field('datasheet');

if( $link ): 
    $link_url = $link['url'];
    $link_title = $link['title'];
    $link_target = $link['target'] ? $link['target'] : '_self';
    ?>
    <a class="button" href="<?php echo esc_url($link_url); ?>" target="<?php echo esc_attr($link_target); ?>"><?php echo esc_html($link_title); ?></a>
<?php
};
add_action( 'ocean_after_single_product_meta', 'product_datasheet_below_summary', 5 );
```

This doesn’t work. I was hoping for a link to the Datasheet, but it simply prints, in plaintext:

```
$link = get_field(‘datasheet’); if( $link ): $link_url = 
$link[‘url’]; $link_title = $link[‘title’]; $link_target = 
$link[‘target’] ? $link[‘target’] : ‘_self’; ?>
```

followed by a generic square button link.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks very much for your help.

---

Thanks for your advice. Instead of using Code Snippets I just created a child theme and edited the relevant .php file, adding the following:

`

```
                if( $link ): 
                    $link_url = $link['url'];
                    $link_title = $link['title'];
                    $link_target = $link['target'] ? $link['target'] : '_self';
                    ?>
            <a class= "button" id="datasheet-button" href="<?php echo esc_url($link_url); ?>" target="<?php echo esc_attr($link_target); ?>"><?php echo esc_html($link_title); ?></a>
            <?php endif; ?>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting plaintext after the first `?>` because that's a `php` ending tag, and the Code Snippets plugin doesn't allow for multiple `php` statements and is simply crashing and dumping plain text rather than executing code.

You need to rewrite the whole function as one `php` statement and `echo` all the button `html`, along with the `php` variables delimited in the `html` with `.`'s. A simple example:

```
<?php 
$var = "Hello World";
echo "<p>The value of the variable is : " . $var . "</p>";
?>
```

And you may need to use the more standard ACF get field construct, too:

`$value = get_field( "text_field" );`

Search SE for more examples of echoing `html` in `php`.

Comment: The use of get_field and using $link["url"] is correct as it means he has the field set up as a link object so he needs to grab the values from the array.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Instead of using Code Snippets I just created a child theme and edited the relevant .php file, adding the following:

`<?php 
     $link = get_field('datasheet');

     if( $link ): 
      $link_url = $link['url'];
      $link_title = $link['title'];
      $link_target = $link['target'] ? $link['target'] : '_self';
      ?>
    <a class= "button" id="datasheet-button" href="<?php echo esc_url($link_url); ?>" target="<?php echo esc_attr($link_target); ?>"><?php echo esc_html($link_title); ?></a>
    <?php endif; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Your function is a bit all over the place, I have cleaned it up to work in the output you want it to using an object instead of echoing out multiple parts of the button code. This in my opinion is easier to manage and looks nicer as it keeps the HTML and PHP code as separate as possible:

```
function product_datasheet_below_summary() {
    $link = get_field('datasheet');

    if( $link ){
        $link_url = $link['url'];
        $link_title = $link['title'];
        $link_target = $link['target'] ? $link['target'] : '_self';
    } ob_start();?>

    <?php if($link):?>
        <a class="button" href="<?php echo $link_url;?>" target="<?php echo $link_target;?>"><?php echo $link_title;?></a>
    <?php endif;

    return ob_get_clean();
} add_action( 'ocean_after_single_product_meta', 'product_datasheet_below_summary', 5 );?>
```